# Best way to find eigenvalues?

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue

I have an equation `AX= nBX` where `A` and `B` are matrices of the same order and `X` is the `coefficient matrix`. And `n` are the `eigenvalues` to be found out.

Now, I know `X` which I obtain by imposing the necessary boundary conditions.

What is the best possible way to find the `eigenvalues 'n'` and why ?

```
A1=np.dot(A,X)

B1=np.dot(B,X)

n=eigvals(A1,B1)
```

OR

```
n,yhat=eig(A,B).
```

Comment: Do you actually know all elements of `A`, `B`, and `X`? It seems to trivialize the problem.

Comment: Neither `numpy.linalg.eig` nor `numpy.linalg.eigvals` takes two arguments. This doesn't look like an eigenvalue computation at all.

Comment: Yes I do know all the elements of A,B and X. I have to find out the values of 'n'.  Kindly explain knowing all the matrices, how does it trivialise the problem.

Comment: There are 3 cases. Case 1: `AX=BX=0`. In that case, any value of `n` is valid. Case 2: `BX!=0`, but `AX` is a scalar multiple of `BX`. In that case, `n` must be whatever multiple `AX` is of `BX`. Case 3: `AX` is not a scalar multiple of `BX`. In that case, no values of `n` are possible. Given that you speak of eigenvalues, plural, you seem to have a different mental model of the situation.

Comment: If you're already willing to take the computational burden of computing `AX` and `BX`, the whole thing reduces to a big system of m*n linear equations in 1 variable, where m and n are the numbers of rows and columns in `AX` and `BX`.

Comment: Say, X is totally unknown to me. Then is it possible to find out 'n'?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming X is unknown, you want

```
eigenvalues = scipy.linalg.eigvals(A, B)
```

If you also want eigenvectors, you want

```
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = scipy.linalg.eig(A, B)
```

It doesn't make much sense to treat this as an eigenvalue problem if X is known. If X is known, you might as well just multiply and see if AX is a multiple of BX.